# How to covert video and extract frame from video using FFMPEG in single command

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to convert and extract image frame from a video file in single command
I can do this in 2 steps but I want to use pipe like technique to do this

This is what I have:
`for %%a in ("*.avi") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 20 -c:a libvo_aacenc -b:a 128k "%%~na.mp4"`  <-- converts correctly

I need to incorporate this extract command:

```
ffmpeg -i inputfile.avi  -r  1  -t  4  image-%d.jpeg
```

Merging two commands giving error.

How do I do it?

**EDIT:**
This is what I have. But it just converts the video, no jpg image created as second output

```
for %%a in ("*.avi") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 20 -c:a libvo_aacenc -b:a 128k "%%~na.mp4" | ffmpeg -r 1 -s 4cif "%%~na.jpeg"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a code block like below in which the 2 output are separate by their options.

And note that i added %%05d in your jpg file name to hots the image number.

```
 for %%a in ("*.avi") do (
    fffmpeg -i "%%a" -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 20 -c:a libvo_aacenc -b:a 128k "%%~na.mp4" -r 1 -s 4cif -t 4 "%%~na%%05d.jpg"
  )
```

Comment: I don't want to run 2 separate commands. ffmpeg is 25MB in size.

Comment: Ok I was wrong you want a cmd line to decode 1x and have encoder behind to save memory and cpu usage. It should be possible! But I don't know the syntax

Comment: I just edited my answer with something better... based on the ffmpeg documentation you can but several output directly separate by their options.

Comment: It works but somehow it creates 13 jpg images for each video while I want 3 images. I am playing with the script. I changed %%05d with %%01d but stil creates 13 images.

Comment: that detail wasn't explicit in the question and I didn't put a -t option in the cmd (see the edit) note that it's a number of second so the num of frame can change depending of the frame rate.

Comment: I added extra parameter which fixed it. Cool.